# When will webkit phase out Web SQL?

Tags: webkit

I have a wrapper which works with indexedDB as well but find web sql to be a lot easier to query. How long can I rely on Web SQL being in Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're not going to get a definitive answer on this one. my brief search of http://bugs.webkit.org didn't reveal a "remove Web SQL" ticket, but that doesn't mean it's not there. But if there is an answer to your question, that's where it will be.